# What are your strategies to keep the memory usage low?

Tags: ruby, memory-management, garbage-collection

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) is truly memory-hungry - but also worth every single bit.

What do you do to keep the memory usage low? Do you avoid big strings and use smaller arrays/hashes instead or is it no problem to concern about for you and let the garbage collector do the job?

**Edit**: I found a nice article about this topic [here](http://gnomecoder.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/rubys-garbage-collection-problem/) - old but still interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Choose date structures that are efficient representations, scale well, and do what you need.
2. Use algorithms that work using efficient data structures rather than bloated, but easier ones.
3. Look else where. Ruby has a C bridge and its much easier to be memory conscious in C than in Ruby.

Comment: The C-bridge isn't well documented and you'll always have to look yourself. Most google links are outdated docs/references to non-existing pages. ;)

Answer (score 9):

I've found Phusion's Ruby Enterprise Edition (a fork of mainline Ruby with much-improved garbage collection) to make a dramatic difference in memory usage... Plus, they've made it extraordinarily easy to install (and to remove, if you find the need).

You can find out more and download it on [their website](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/).

Answer (score 8):

I really don't think it matters all that much.
Making your code less readable in order to improve memory consumption is something you should only ever do if you **need** it. And by need, I mean have a **specific case** for the performance profile and  **specific metrics** that indicate that any change will address the issue.

If you have an application where memory is going to be the limiting factor, then Ruby may not be the best choice. That said, I have found that my Rails apps generally consume about 40-60mb of RAM per Mongrel instance. In the scheme of things, this isn't very much.

You might be able to run your application on the JVM with JRuby - the Ruby VM is currently not as advanced as the JVM for memory management and garbage collection. The 1.9 release is adding many improvements and there are alternative VM's under development as well.

Comment: The problem is not that a mongrel instance needs 60M - it's more that I have to restart mongrel every day to avoid huge leakage - but that's not what I meant with this question. ;)

Comment: Very true. I think one of the BIG gains from Passenger is in terms of the management of the instances. I haven't moved my server over yet, but I am looking to do it soon.

Comment: I actually prefer Thin over Mongrel at the moment - but the problem is Ruby internal. Does the 1.9 include any fixes for the garbage collector?

Comment: The problem is that the JVM adds a whole other suite of performance problems.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby developers are quite lucky since they don’t have to manage the memory themselves.

Be aware that ruby allocates objects, for instance something as simple as

```
100.times{ 'foo' }
```

allocates 100 string objects (strings are mutable and each version requires its own memory allocation).

Make sure that if you are using a library allocating a lot of objects, that other alternatives are not available and your choice is worth paying the garbage collector cost. (you might not have a lot of requests/s or might not care for a few dozen ms per requests).

Creating a hash object really allocates more than an object, for instance

`{'joe' => 'male', 'jane' => 'female'}`

doesn’t allocate 1 object but 7. (one hash, 4 strings + 2 key strings)

If you can use symbol keys as they won’t be garbage collected. However because they won’t be garbage collected you want to make sure to not use totally dynamic keys like converting the username to a symbol, otherwise you will ‘leak’ memory.

**Example:** Somewhere in your app, you apply a to_sym on an user’s name like :

```
hash[current_user.name.to_sym] = something
```

When you have hundreds of users, that’s could be ok, but what is happening if you have one million of users ? Here are the numbers :

```
ruby-1.9.2-head >
# Current memory usage : 6608K
# Now, add one million randomly generated short symbols
ruby-1.9.2-head > 1000000.times { (Time.now.to_f.to_s).to_sym }

# Current memory usage : 153M, even after a Garbage collector run.

# Now, imagine if symbols are just 20x longer than that ?
ruby-1.9.2-head > 1000000.times { (Time.now.to_f.to_s * 20).to_sym }
# Current memory usage : 501M
```

Be aware to never convert non controlled arguments in symbol or check arguments before, this can easily lead to a denial of service.

Also remember to avoid nested loops more than three levels deep because it makes the maintenance difficult. Limiting nesting of loops and functions to three levels or less is a good rule of thumb to keep the code performant.

Here are some links in regards:

[http://merbist.com](http://merbist.com/2010/07/29/object-allocation-why-you-should-care/)

[http://blog.monitis.com](http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2012/02/08/20-ruby-performance-tips/)

Answer (score 5):

1. When deploying a Rails/Rack webapp, use REE or some other copy-on-write friendly interpreter.
2. Tweak the garbage collector (see https://www.engineyard.com/blog/tuning-the-garbage-collector-with-ruby-1-9-2 for example)
3. Try to cut down the number of external libraries/gems you use since additional code uses memory.
4. If you have a part of your app that is really memory-intensive then it's maybe worth rewriting it in a C extension or completing it by invoking other/faster/better optimized programs (if you have to process vast amounts of text data, maybe you can replace that code with calls to grep, awk, sed etc.)

Comment: Is there any evidence that loading code takes up a lot of memory?

Comment: If I generate a new Rails app and start the console, it uses around 65 MB of memory. If I add the Gemfile of a large Rails app and start the console again, it uses around 180 MB of memory.

Comment: link is broken!

Comment: @Cyzanfar link is fixed, but I'm sure there is more up-to-date information to be found somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 3):

I am not a ruby developer but I think some techniques and methods are true of any language:

Use the minimum size variable suitable for the job
Destroy and close variables and connections when not in use
However if you have an object you will need to use many times consider keeping it in scope
Any loops with manipulations of a big string dp the work on a smaller string and then append to bigger string

Use decent (try catch finally) error handling to make sure objects and connections are closed

When dealing with data sets only return the minimum necessary

Comment: In Ruby it's a bit worse, because the garbage collection can take a lot of time and you can't destroy a variable directly.

Comment: bad advice. Keep variables in scope longer, but strings are the killer for memory - appending does too much memory reallocs, so appending may even be your problem in the first place.

Comment: Yes but sometimes it is unavoidable to have to append a string etc. It is better to do any work on a smaller string then add it on the larger. In .net I would use a string builder for this. He wanted to reduce memory usage and if you were not using a variable why keep it around?

Comment: "Use the minimum size variable suitable for the job" - this does not apply to Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Other than in extreme cases memory usage isn't something to worry about.  The time you spend trying to reduce memory usage will buy a *LOT* of gigabytes.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Small Memory Software - Patterns for Systems with Limited Memory](http://www.cix.co.uk/~smallmemory/). You don't specify what sort of memory constraint, but I assume RAM. While not Ruby-specific, I think you'll find some useful ideas in this book - the patterns cover RAM, ROM and secondary storage, and are divided into major techniques of small data structures, memory allocation, compression, secondary storage, and small architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing we've ever had which has actually been worth worrying about is RMagick.

The solution is to make sure you're using RMagick version 2, and call [`Image#destroy!`](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#destroy_bang) when you're done using your image

Answer (score 2):

Avoid code like this:

```
str = ''
veryLargeArray.each do |foo|
  str += foo
  # but str << foo is fine (read update below)
end
```

which will create each intermediate string value as a String object and then remove its only reference on the next iteration. This junks up the memory with tons of increasingly long strings that have to be garbage collected.

Instead, use `Array#join`:

```
str = veryLargeArray.join('')
```

This is implemented in C very efficiently and doesn't incur the String creation overhead.

UPDATE: Jonas is right in the comment below. My warning holds for `+=` but not `<<`.

Comment: *increasingly long strings* - will it really? `+=` has that problem but `<<` is an append.

Comment: That's good to know! I have updated my answer. So `<<` destructively updates the string it's called on, rather than returning a new String like `+=` does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new at Ruby, but so far I haven't found it necessary to do anything special in this regard (that is, beyond what I just tend to do as a programmer generally).  Maybe this is because memory is cheaper than the time it would take to seriously optimize for it (my Ruby code runs on machines with 4-12 GB of RAM).  It might also be because the jobs I'm using it for are not long-running (i.e. it's going to depend on your application).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Python, but I guess the strategies are similar.

I try to use small functions/methods, so that local variables get automatically garbage collected when you return to the caller.

In larger functions/methods I explicitly delete large temporary objects (like lists) when they are no longer needed. Closing resources as early as possible might help too.

Comment: That's a solution, but in Ruby there's no way to explicit delete an object. There aren't even any destructors. Sometimes the Ruby-way is a bit strange. ;)

Comment: Or contrary, non-Ruby way is strange with its destructors :)  Digging further, destructors/finalizers are actually [an odd concept and are implemented in some odd ways in many languages](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/17155).  But if you really really need it, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956067/ruby-destructors) to learn about `ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`.  Of course this non-OOP-looking method is odd and discouraged because finalizers are odd and discouraged :)

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind is the life cycle of your objects. If you're objects are not passed around that much, the garbage collector will eventually kick in and free them up. However, if you keep referencing them it may require some cycles for the garbage collector to free them up. This is particularly true in Ruby 1.8, where the garbage collector uses a poor implementation of the mark and sweep technique.

You may run into this situation when you try to apply some "design patterns" like decorator that keep objects in memory for a long time. It may not be obvious when trying example in isolation, but in real world applications where thousands of objects are created at the same time the cost of memory growth will be significant.

Answer (score 1):

When possible, use arrays instead of other data structures.  Try not to use floats when integers will do.

Be careful when using gem/library methods.  They may not be memory optimized.  For example, the Ruby PG::Result class has a method 'values' which is not optimized.  It will use a lot of extra memory.  I have yet to report this.

Comment: Where did you hear that arrays are different from other data structures memory-wise, and that floats take up memory?

Comment: Typically, ints take up 4 bytes, and floats take up 8 bytes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067249/easiest-way-to-determine-sizeof-double-and-sizeof-int-from-ruby

Comment: Also, the suggestion about arrays is that they typically requires less overhead.  Different implementations of Ruby might differ of course.  But this is a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing malloc(3) implementation to [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) will immediately decrease your memory consumption up to 30%. I've created 'jemalloc' gem to achieve this instantly.

- ['jemalloc' GEM: Inject jemalloc(3) into your Ruby app in 3 min](http://kzk9.net/je-gem-instant-perf-improvement-and-memory-us)

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep arrays & lists & datasets as small as possible. The individual object do not matter much, as creation and garbage collection is pretty fast in most modern languages.

In the cases you have to read some sort of huge dataset from the database, make sure to read in a forward/only manner and process it in little bits instead og loading everything into memory first.

Answer (score 0):

dont use a lot of symbols, they stay in memory until the process gets killed.. this because symbols never get garbage collected.

Comment: Rather: Use a lot of symbols but remember their purpose. Never treat them as lightweight strings.  [http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/]