# Easiest way to determine sizeof( double ) and sizeof( int ) from Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, sizeof, unpack

For unpacking complex binary strings with mixed doubles and integers using Ruby's [String.unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112) I need to determine offsets within the binary string. Commonly, doubles are 8 bytes and integers are 4 bytes, but in order to make my code machine-independent, I would like to query these sizes from within my Ruby code.

What is the easiest way to determine the size of integers and doubles from within Ruby, i.e., request the response of a request to C's `sizeof( type )` method?

Comment: where does the data come from? is the Ruby script necessarily run on the architecture which produces the values?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do?  As @Cristoph indicates, the size is dependent on the program and platform that produced the binary strings, not the ruby program and platform consuming them.  Any binary interface specification should have the layout explicitly specified somewhere (item size, endianness, padding, etc)

Comment: Yes, the question is under the assumption that the binary string was generated on the same machine as the recipient Ruby script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a workable solution, by using [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206), the inverse method of `String#unpack`. By packing a string of 1 integer or 1 double it is possible to determine the size of integers and doubles from within ruby itself which gives the same results as using `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(double)` (because of the implementation of `Array#pack` in C):

```
[1.to_i].pack("i").size # 4
[1.to_f].pack("d").size # 8
```

Answer (score 2):

This is so obvious that i am probably missing the point:

```
puts 1.size #=> 4
puts (256**10 - 1).size   #=> 12
```

Comment: Heh? The size of an int (making sure with `puts 1.to_i.size`) results in 8 on my machine (MBP, ruby 1.8,7), not 4, which is `sizeof( int )` in C.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a 64 bit processor, mine is 32 bit. I have no idea how C handles this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Ruby language or its build/distribution system. However, the existence of [Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) suggests that it's possible to create custom files on package installation - for example a configuration file which exports the result of the following commands as Ruby constants:

```
echo __SIZEOF_INT__ | gcc -E -P -
echo __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ | gcc -E -P -
```

Comment: I can't get this to output anything else but the literal/original `__SIZEOF_INT__` or `__SIZEOF_DOUBLE__` strings (using gcc 4.2.1 on a mac or gcc 4.1.2 on a linux box, with or without `-c`).

Comment: according to my google-fu, the patch dates from 2007; no idea when it was first included in a release, but I can confirm that it's in 4.3.4...

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to have a small C program, `sizeofdouble.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf( "%lu", sizeof(double) );
}
```

which, when compiled to a `sizeofdouble` executable can be called from ruby with

```
sizeofdouble = `./sizeofdouble`.to_i
```

but that's an ugly hack, rather than a clean solution to this problem.

Comment: your C program is not portable, as `sizeof (long) == sizeof (size_t)` is not necessarily true; either use the `z` length modifier (which is not universally supported) or cast to `unsigned` (no need for `unsigned long`)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party here, but ruby's `Fiddle` library exposes the sizes of all the data types you might want as constants. Here are the results on my system (64-bit MacOS 10.13):

```
require 'fiddle'

Fiddle::SIZEOF_SHORT   # => 2
Fiddle::SIZEOF_INT     # => 4
Fiddle::SIZEOF_DOUBLE  # => 8
Fiddle::SIZEOF_SIZE_T  # => 8
Fiddle::SIZEOF_SSIZE_T # => 8
```

[See the ruby docs here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html#SIZEOF_CHAR)