# Count initializations of Ruby Class

Tags: ruby, count, instantiation

Is there a way to **count** the amount of **instances** that get created as long as the program is running?

Something like

```
class Foo      
    @bar = 0

    def initialize
        @bar += 1
    end
end
```

won't work (`@bar` is `nil` in `initialize`).

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794896/how-to-count-existing-instances-of-a-class-in-ruby

Comment: Do you care about instances that are abandoned and garbage collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables belong to objects (aka instances), that's why they are called instance variables after all. Your first `@bar` is an instance variable of `Foo`, your second `@bar` is an instance variable of the newly-created instance of `Foo`. Those are two completely different objects (they aren't even of the same class: the newly-created instance is of class `Foo`, whereas `Foo` is of class `Class`).

You obviously need to increment `@bar` in a method called on `Foo`, not in a method called on instances of `Foo`. So, can we think about a method that is a) called on `Foo` and b) called everytime an instance is created? What about `new`?

```
class Foo
  @bar = 0

  def self.new(*)
    @bar += 1
    super
  end
end
```

Okay, technically speaking, this doesn't count the number of instances, only the number of times `new` was called. Sometimes, instances get created without calling `new`, e.g. when de-serializing. This should be the closest you can get without resorting to ugly hacks of the interpreter internals.

You might think you can override `allocate` instead (I thought so, too), but I just tested it and it doesn't work. Presumably, the default implementation of `new` doesn't call `allocate` via normal means but actually uses the interpreter internal implementation directly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class variable instead of an instance variable:

```
class Foo
  @@count = 0
  def initialize
    @@count += 1
  end

  def Foo.get_count
    @@count
  end
end

foo1 = Foo.new
foo2 = Foo.new
foo3 = Foo.new

puts Foo.get_count
# => 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, this example actually works, but for me, this is not a solution since I need to count the instances of three classes which all extend one module. I can't figure out how to use this as a class variable in a module.