# How to count the number of objects created in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to count the total number of objects created in a Ruby application? If so, how can I do it?

I know how to count the number of instances of a given class I create, as of in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794896/how-to-count-existing-instances-of-a-class-in-ruby), but is there a way to get the number of objects created of any class in an application (including internal ones)?

Comment: `ObjectSpace.count_objects`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is the correct answer. Will you post it as such?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is this useful?

Comment: @DamianoStoffie: memory usage optimization, I assume.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
ObjectSpace.count_objects
```

For example, this is what it outputs on a fresh IRB session:

```
{
        :TOTAL => 30161,
         :FREE => 378,
     :T_OBJECT => 152,
      :T_CLASS => 884,
     :T_MODULE => 30,
      :T_FLOAT => 4,
     :T_STRING => 11517,
     :T_REGEXP => 165,
      :T_ARRAY => 3395,
       :T_HASH => 180,
     :T_STRUCT => 2,
     :T_BIGNUM => 2,
       :T_FILE => 15,
       :T_DATA => 1680,
      :T_MATCH => 99,
    :T_COMPLEX => 1,
       :T_NODE => 11620,
     :T_ICLASS => 37
}
```